# Не получается получить корректные данные от онлайн-оплаты POST методом в Node.js

Tags: javascript, php, json, node.js, post

Подключаю WayForPay. В документации (https://wiki.wayforpay.com/uk/view/852102) есть пример получения данных результата оплаты:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
```

У меня back-end на Node.js.
Для получение данных по POST запросу, у меня есть следующий код:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

В самом маршруте для того, чтобы посмотреть что приходит, я записал request.body в файл:

```
fs.writeFileSync("test.txt", JSON.stringify(request.body));
```

Вот что вышло:

```
{"{\"merchantAccount\":\"test_merch_n1\",\"orderReference\":\"ID22311535560371\",\"merchantSignature\":\"8e010ca8a4175ad7bb78200b5fa4e0b4\",\"amount\":0.07,\"currency\":\"USD\",\"authCode\":\"\",\"email\":\"test@gmail.com\",\"phone\":\"380507772233\",\"createdDate\":1603761056,\"processingDate\":1603761101,\"cardPan\":\"23****5687\",\"cardType\":\"MasterCard\",\"issuerBankCountry\":\"Ukraine\",\"issuerBankName\":\"MONObank\",\"recToken\":\"\",\"transactionStatus\":\"Declined\",\"reason\":\"Three Ds Fail\",\"reasonCode\":1108,\"fee\":0,\"paymentSystem\":\"card\",\"acquirerBankName\":\"WayForPay\",\"cardProduct\":\"debit\",\"clientName\":\"\\u0412\\u041b\\u0410\\u0414\\u0418\\u0421\\u041b\\u0410\\u0412 \\u041d\\u0418\\u041a\\u041e\\u0412\",\"baseAmount\":1.99,\"baseCurrency\":\"UAH\"}":""}
```

То есть я не могу обратиться к reasonCode таким образом:

```
request.body.reasonCode
```

Какой аналог следующего PHP-кода на Node.js?

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
```

Comment: приложите к вопросу заголовки запроса на сервер, какой там 'content-type'?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так читать прямо из файла с диска и парсить. Думаю дальше под свои нужды поправите сами.

```javascript
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('student.json', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    let student = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(student);
});

console.log('This is after the read call');
```

Comment: Так в файл я специально сделал запись, чтобы посмотреть что вообще находится в request.body. Мне не нужно было из него читать. Мне нужно было request.body привести в нормальный вид.

Answer (score 0):

Мне пришло тело запроса в виде {"{данные_которые_мне_нужны}": ""}
Я взял этот ключ и распарсил его.

```
let body = JSON.parse(Object.keys(request.body)[0]);
```

В итоге получил объект с данными, как и должно быть. После этого можно обращаться к полям.

```
body.reasonCode // 1108
```

Получился костыль. Думаю, что должно быть решение лучше.

Comment: у вас проблема: вы либо не посылаете json как json, с правильным content-type, либо не обрабатываете его как json на сервере. ещё раз предлагаю показать заголовки запроса отправляемого на сервер. и удалить ответ, который должен был быть правкой вопроса

Comment: Запрос на сервер делаю не я. Его формирует сервис онлайн-оплаты. Данные не в JSON. Это application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Но bodyParser все равно должен был распарсить запрос и поместить объект в request.body.

Comment: Заголовки: "connection":"close","content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","x-forwarded-proto":"https, https","accept":"*/*","content-length":"700","host":"api.testsite.com","x-forwarded-for":"88.85.72.203, 88.85.72.203","!~passenger-proto":"https","!~passenger-client-address":"88.85.72.203","!~passenger-envvars":"VU5JUVVFX0lEAFg1bUdFLUx3RGpYWFdXQG8zWlZ2WXdBQUFBWQBIVFRQUwBvbgA="

Comment: теперь стало понятно. попробуйте https://stackoverflow.com/a/45352933/4496422. если не получится: попробуйте варианты с extended: false и закомментированным  app.use(bodyParser.json());